# PHP Slim retrieve variables

Tags: php, url-rewriting, slim

Essentially I want that when a user type `category/business` for instance, it renders `searchPage.php?crs_category=business`

I tried doing it as follow, but the functions inside that page do not seem able to fetch the variable. When directly directly to `searchPage.php?crs_category=business` it is able to.

```
$app->get('/category/:name', function ($name) use($app){
  $app->render("searchPage.php", array('crs_category' => $name));
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I do not want to use htaccess to rewritte rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try (also check if this is surely a get request [rather than post]):

```
$app->get('/category/:name', function ($name) use($app) {
    $app->render("searchPage.php", array('crs_category' => $name));
});
$app->run();
```

Comment: Hi would you mind explaining as to why no php code even a simple echo command is not executed on a rendered page?

Comment: I don't see the rest of your code. You might have forgotten the run() command but I am not sure.